# Compiling a kernel version(Ubuntu/Debian)

Tags: git, ubuntu, linux-kernel, debian, ubuntu-12.04

I've downloaded the latest kernel sources:

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git
cd linux-stable
git tag -l | less
```

and picked v3.9.1.

```
git checkout -b v3.9.1
git branch --set-upstream v3.9.1 origin/master
```

, pulled the distribution:

```
git pull
```

and ran:

```
make kernelversion
```

which always outputs:

```
4.0.0-rc5
```

, an unstable version. How may I download v3.9.1(a stable version)?

**Edit #1:**

The current branches are:

```
$ git branch
  master
* v3.9.1
```

Comment: `git checkout -b v3.9.1`: this creates a *new branch* named `v3.9.1`, completely ignoring the *existing tag* `v3.9.1`.  So you're now all set to continue developing 4.4.0-rc5 on your branch.  Not sure about the rest, but you certainly want to get off this new branch and delete it; perhaps you want to check out the existing tag (detached HEAD) as well.

Comment: @torek How is it possible to pull v3.9.1?

Comment: remove the -b, git checkout v3.9.1

Comment: You don't really "pull versions" in git: `pull` is just a convenience script that simply does `git fetch` followed by `git merge`.  I suspect you want to check out v3.9.1, which is just `git checkout v3.9.1` (no `-b`).  The problem is that you've created a branch named `v3.9.1` so now `v3.9.1` is ambiguous: did you mean the tag, or the branch?  (The `checkout` command always assumes you mean "the branch", in case of ambiguity.  Other git commands differ.)

Comment: @Sebi: I know that and you know that but `git checkout` believes you mean "the branch".  That's why you must delete this bogus branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `git checkout -b v3.9.1`, you want `git checkout -b mybuild refs/tags/v3.9.1`. That creates a local branch named "mybuild" that points to the same commit that the tag "v3.9.1" does, and checks out that commit. (Note: the "refs/tags/" bit isn't really essential, but it does help avoid ambiguity... `git` will search the tags for something to checkout if none of the branches match)

Comment: `git checkout v3.9.1` should work as well as long you need temporary anonymous branch.